# Mixing android dependency versions error message in build.gradle file, however can't find the dependencies that are different

Tags: android, gradle

I am receiving the following error message in my build.gradle file:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Below is the current state of my build.gradle file. I can't see any explicit reference to the dependencies of differing versions mentioned in the above error message however.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.ideanetwork"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 5
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.18.5"
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare the oldest version dependences with the latest version seems to work. I don't think it's the better solution (maybe it is not a solucion at all), but it dismiss the warning.
It is what am I doing and nothing breaked untill now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will fix the dependency version incompatibility problem.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        // Skip multidex because it follows a different versioning pattern.
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '28.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

}